# Laravel File Upload "Laminas\Diactoros\Exception\InvalidArgumentException"

Tags: laravel, react-native, file-upload

Good day,
I have been running into this exception "Laminas\Diactoros\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: Invalid stream reference provided in file" while trying to upload a video file taken from the camera with react-native-image-picker. Now i ran into this same issue while trying to upload photos some days back till i switched from using "$file->move()" to using "Intervention Image". I dont really understand the error and need some help.

EDIT: I should also mention that when i used postman to upload, it was successful.

Thanks

```
public function save_verification_video(Request $request) {
    /**
     * 'file' => 'mimes:video/x-ms-asf,video/x-flv,video/mp4,application/x-mpegURL,video/MP2T,video/3gpp,video/quicktime,video/x-msvideo,video/x-ms-wmv,video/avi'
     */
    try {
        $validator = $this->validator($request->all(), [
            'glam_id' => '',

        ]);
        if ($validator['failed']) {
            return \prepare_json(false, ['messages' => $validator['messages']],'',$status_code=200);     
        }

        $data = $request->all();

        if ($request->hasFile('body_video') || $request->hasFile('speech_video')) {
            // $this->out->writeln("User ".$user->last_name);
            $file = $request->file('body_video') ?? $request->file('speech_video');
            $verification_type = ($request->hasFile('body_video')) ? 'body_video' : 'speech_video';
            $path = public_path('/uploads/glams/'. $user->code . '/videos/'.$verification_type . '/');
            File::makeDirectory($path, $mode=0777, true, true);

            // $res = MediaUploader::fromFile($file)->upload();
            $res = $file->move($path, $file->getClientOriginalName());
            if ($res) {
                return \prepare_json(true, [],\get_api_string('generic_ok'), $status_code=200);
            }
            else {
                return \prepare_json(false, [],\get_api_string('file_not_ploaded'), $status_code=200);
            }
        }
        else {
            return \prepare_json(false, [],\get_api_string('no_videos'), $status_code=200); 
        }
    }
    catch(\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException $ex) {
        return \prepare_json(false, [], \get_api_string('glam_not_found'));
    }
    catch(\Exception $ex) {
        return \prepare_json(false, [],\get_api_string('error_occured').$ex->getMessage(), $status_code=200);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a server-side error from PHP. You need to show us the server-side PHP code in question, not the JavaScript. And please don't give us screenshots of it; give us the actual code.

Comment: coming right up...

Comment: Does this happen on both android and ios? I had an issue the other week with `react-native-image-picker` on ios not providing a property "name" for the returned image. This lead to me getting an error from my backend saying that I had provided an invalid argument to do the file upload with because this was null.

Comment: i'm currently working with just android, i just checked and there is no name in the returned image also

Comment: I added a name property to the data being sent to the backend and still get this error

Comment: sorry, just checked and it was called `fileName`, just as an example, in case it helps, this is what my preparation of the upload looks like https://gist.github.com/leighquince/7acea096ecb6cbbafcbc575bded1a15a

Comment: um... i dont have an issue with image upload, my issue is with video upload. the video data returned is "Response =  path: {"/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/VID_20200325_150216.mp4", uri: "content://media/external/video/media/148020"}"

Comment: no name,type,size etc etc info that comes if it was an image captured.

Comment: in my case, increasing upload_max_filesize in php.ini file, fixed the problem.

Comment: mine was an issue with RN... it couldn't access the file in my camera folder... so i had to move the file to another directory first then create my JS file object then upload.